# i want to get logo and categories side by side to create a menu

Tags: html, css

```css
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}



.main-nav img {
  width: 7rem;
}

.main-nav__items {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5rem;
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

.main-nav li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <img src="img/Disney-Logo.png">
    <ul class="main-nav__items">
      <li>ana sayfa</li>
      <li>arama</li>
      <li>izleme listem</li>
      <li>originals</li>
      <li>filmler</li>
      <li>diziler</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="profile">
    <span>Kaan Karakuş</span>
    <div class="profile_photo">

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want to put the logo next to the ul element but result :
I want to put 3 elements side by side like this, but somehow I couldn't get these two to line up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8HQE.png)

Comment: add `display: flex;` to `main-nav` class and `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

See below. Using `display: flex` on the items within the header causes the items to line up nicely.

```css
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav img {
  width: 7rem;
}

.main-nav__items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

.main-nav li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
    <ul class="main-nav__items">
      <li>ana sayfa</li>
      <li>arama</li>
      <li>izleme listem</li>
      <li>originals</li>
      <li>filmler</li>
      <li>diziler</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="profile">
    <span>Kaan Karakuş</span>
    <div class="profile_photo">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/30">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: If this works for you can you mark the answer as correct please? I'm a tart for reputation points :-D